# ¿Puede Google reCaptcha garantizarme el origen de la solicitud?

Tags: javascript, api, recaptcha

#### Contexto

Tengo una aplicación web que está dividida en 2 partes, Cliente (En JS, etc) y Servidor (API en PHP). El problema es que actualmente el registro también se hace desde el lado del cliente enviando peticiones al servidor, y esto implica que cualquier persona pueda realizar las mismas peticiones desde otra interfaz, y quiero que el registro solo se pueda hacer desde mi propia interfaz.

#### Pregunta

Para ello estoy usando reCaptcha de Google, pero quiero saber si esto me garantiza que solo los dominios indicados pueden validarlo correctamente. Es decir, que no puede llegar pepito, "clonar" la estructura del formulario y hacer la misma petición a la API con mi recaptcha en otro dominio o en local.

> Sé que hay otras opciones como Tokens CSRF, pero no quiero usar código
> de servidor en el cliente (en la parte de JS) porque sino, dejará de
> ser "Solo cliente" y esto implica que ya no puede ser hosteada en
> Firebase y los demás hostings de webs estáticas. Tampoco se puede
> encargar de ello la API porque pasaría lo mismo, cualquier usuario
> podría obtener tokens y realizar las peticiones del mismo modo. Sé que
> lo que intento puede ser imposible, pero, ¿reCaptcha es una solución
> para ello?

Comment: *para generarlos debo usar algo de código PHP en la app* hmmm, que yo sepa php es unicamente un lenguaje de servidor. Si te refieres a que tu web debe gestionar el código del csrf... si bueno, si quieres hacerlo así, si. Por qué no se encarga de eso también la api??? De todas maneras, no rompe ningún esquema que el cliente tenga *lógica* para encargarse de cosas del cliente... de hecho, es lo más común del mundo. Siempre hay cosas que **deben** hacerse en front, y no pasa nada por hacerlas!

Comment: Sí, pero si la API se encarga de generar el token, y mi app puede obtenerlo, cualquier otra persona puede hacerlo no? Y no me gustaría usar lenguaje de servidor en cliente porque no funcionaría en ningún servidor como Firebase, Netlify, etc. (Sé que seguramente esté intentando hacer algo que básicamente es imposible) Muhas graciass!

Comment: No tengo muy claro a qué tipo de cliente te refieres. Si pudieses especificar más, sería más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: He intentado explicarlo mejor. Un saludo!